# How can I get my Table View in xcode 4.6 ios6 working?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios6, xcode4.6

I realize there are many posts like mine, but I still can't get the code working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't have all of the methods I want to implement implemented, so dont' worry about those. The error comes right after I link the `tableview` in the `xib` to the data source and delegate.

Let me know if I should post anything else that is relevant.

error:

```
2013-06-03 10:57:16.814 WID Sign-in[7587:11303] -[UITableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb3b0800
2013-06-03 10:57:16.816 WID Sign-in[7587:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb3b0800'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0x1d1f4bd 0x1c83bbc 0x1c8394e 0x1fa548 0x1fd224 0xc1952 0xc12dc 0xc4dd6 0xc9a7e 0x662dd 0x10e56b0 0x2290fc0 0x228533c 0x2290eaf 0x1052bd 0x4db56 0x4c66f 0x4c589 0x4b7e4 0x4b61e 0x4c3d9 0x4f2d2 0xf999c 0x46574 0x4676f 0x46905 0x4f917 0x2cdb 0x13157 0x13747 0x1494b 0x25cb5 0x26beb 0x18698 0x1befdf9 0x1befad0 0x1c09bf5 0x1c09962 0x1c3abb6 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1417a 0x15ffc 0x291d 0x2845 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *existingNames;
    NSMutableArray *existingCompanies;
    NSMutableArray *currentNames;
    NSMutableArray *currentCompanies;
IBOutlet UITableView *preExisting;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *existingNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *existingCompanies;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentCompanies;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *company;


- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addExisting:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize name, company, existingNames, existingCompanies, currentNames, currentCompanies;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [existingCompanies count]; // <------- here there is the problem with iOS 5.1, also [array1 count]
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:
            UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[existingCompanies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

return cell;
}


- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
BOOL exists = [existingNames containsObject:name.text];

if(exists == FALSE){
    [existingNames addObject:name.text];
    [existingCompanies addObject:company.text];
}

[currentNames addObject:name.text];
[currentCompanies addObject:company.text];

name.text=@"";
company.text=@"";

// Set the delegate and datasource. Don't expect picker view to work
// correctly if you don't set it.

}

- (IBAction)addExisting:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you log existingCompanies. Also, where are you adding the data to it? It says you are calling "numberOfRowsInSection" to a UITableView. It doesn't look like the line you commented is the problem. Have you set an exception breakpoint?

Comment: I haven't added any data yet this time, it has failed otherwise in the same way. Does it break without any data, or should it have a blank table view when ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not initiated my NSMutableArrays correctly as well as declaring them in my .h, where this unnecessary. Thanks to those who tried to help!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've wired up your tableview datasource incorrectly.

> [UITableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0xb3b0800'

This is saying that the framework attempted to call the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` selector on an object that does not conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Comment: +1 to you... you were 7 seconds faster than me on the "POST" button, Chris

Comment: Are you saying I can't use the NSMutableArray like I am trying? Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: No, in interface builder (I assume you are using this) you have ctrl dragged the tableview datasource back on to the tableview. You need to make sure the tableview datasource is the ViewController.

Comment: You can use NSMutableArray as a datasource, check your outlets in Interface Builder for your `preExisting` outlet, it should have a `dataSource` property and it seems you've got that wired to the wrong thing.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my confusion. I have linked the table view to the view controller (.xib ctrl clicked to the .h) to the interface builder and also as a property (separately), each resulting in the same error. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @ChrisWagner - NSMutableArray doesn't directly conform to the UITableViewDataSource protocol. You'd have to subclass NSMutableArray or put it into the view controller (as an ivar or property), like the O.P. has already done.

Comment: You're correct and I may have said that confusingly @MichaelDautermann, I was more trying to say you can use an `NSMutableArray` as the backing collection for your `UITableViewDataSource`. @NetworkIntern check out this screenshot, you should end up with something similar, http://www.galloway.me.uk/media/images/custom-uitableviewcell/ib-tableview-links.png, your dataSource should be linked to the File's Owner

Comment: My table view's dataSource and delegate have both been linked to File's Owner, as I mentioned in the OP. This is the step causing the error.

Comment: I guess I didn't not specify that I had linked the dataSource and delegate to the File's Owner. That is what I linked the table view to.

Comment: I would suggest taking a step back and understanding UITableView better. There are many tutorials on the topic, here is one that looks pretty solid. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ Based on the logs you've provided the `dataSource` is the issue, it's probably just a small oversight where a configuration was done improperly. Depending on how far you've gotten you may even want to delete the scene in the Storyboard and rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've started from scratch a few times now and I've followed a few tutorials, including the one you just suggested, already.

Comment: I think my problem was just over-initiation. I had declared my mutable arrays in a couple different places (the .h and the .m). I believe I'm finally getting it to work.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have designated your table view outlet as your data source and not your view controller.

Change the data source to be the view controller and that data source method should be called correctly.